# I can't use PDFlatex using apple mac!

Tags: installing, mactex, texshop, mac

I have recently joined the mac club and I am having trouble using pdflatex. I have installed MacTex which should have everything included but when trying to run typeset I receive the error

> '/usr/texbin/pdflatex does not exist. TeXShop is  a front end for TeX,
>   but you also need a TeX distribution. Perhaps such a distribution was
>   not installed or was removed during a system upgrade. If so, go to
>   http://www.tug.org/mactex/ and follow the instructions to (re)install
>   MacTeX. A less likely possibility is that a tool path is incorrectly
>   configured in TeXShop preferences. This can happen if you are using
>   the macports or fink distributions.'

I have searched for pdflatex and could not find it anywhere...can anyone help me? I have read other forums which say reinstalling MacTex doesn't work and I also did this and it made no difference.

Extra info:

OS 10.10.1 Yosemite
I have reasonable experience using linux / terminal

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! Did you try the 'fix MacTeX' utility from the MacTeX site?

Comment: For some reason texbin is a file, not a folder?? I guess that could be the problem?

Comment: @MichaelHemming It should be a link. For example, `ls -l /usr` gives me `lrwxr-xr-x     1 root  wheel     63  6 Jun  2014 texbin -> /Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 7):

I think I figured it out.

Go into your terminal and type in: 
`which pdftex`

You should get some sort of directory where your latex is installed. like:
`/opt/local/bin/pdftex`

What you should do now is to change the directory where TexShop looks.

Do this by going into Preferences > Engine: and changing the path settings to the directory that `which pdftex` gave out.

I put `/opt/local/bin/` and it worked out for me.

Looking around on the internet tells me that this is a macports problem. So you have to change it manually.

Comment: Ah, macports. Everyone's favorite package manager to hate on :) It's generally advised to not deal with TeX stuff using package managers -- the interdependencies are too complicated for a large-scale manager to really do well. (Aside, homebrew > macports `;)`.)

Comment: This didn't work for me, I typed 'which pdftex' into terminal and got no output.

Comment: which pdflatex returns nothing!

Comment: Then LaTeX is probably not installed correctly.