# pdflatex not found on OS X

Tags: texlive, mactex, texshop

I just install MacTex and trying to compile my tex file with TeXShop:

> Can't find required tool.
>
> /usr/texbin/pdflatex does not exist. TeXShop is  a front end for TeX,
>   but you also need a TeX distribution. Perhaps such a distribution was
>   not installed or was removed during a system upgrade. If so, go to
>   http://tug.org/MacTeX and follow the instructions to (re)install
>   MacTeX. A less likely possibility is that a tool path is incorrectly
>   configured in TeXShop preferences. This can happen if you are using
>   the macports or fink distributions.

I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225361/i-cant-use-pdflatex-using-apple-mac) similar but I got `pdftex not found` after typing  `which pdftex`.

Also, I try to find something like `FixMacTeX2013.pkg` of `/Applications/TeX/` directory according to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171291/95054) and get a `Setup-2015.pkg`. Nothing happens after installation.

What could I fix it?

> OS X EI Capitan 10.11.3

Comment: Exactly which mactex did you install? El Capitan does not allow /usr/texbin any more. AFAIK mactex 2015 and the included texshop does not use /usr/texbin and thus this problem should not occur.

Comment: @daleif It is `TeXLive-2015` that I've installed

Comment: what if you change the first box in texshop preferences / engine / path settings to: /Library/TeX/texbin ?